# Accessing the index of a module installed in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I cannot figure out how to access module I have installed. 
I did all the instructions (adding lines in config/main.php)

I want to access the index page of the module

my file structure from my basic root is the following

```
\assets
\css
\protected
  ...

  \layouts
    main.php  // I want to add a link in my menu, something like
                 array('label'=>'Vote', 'url'=>array('poll/index'))

  \modules
    \poll
      \views
        \poll
          index.php    

  ...
  \views
    \post
      index.php    --> basic page of my site
```

I'd like to access the index module page from my main menu ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can just access your module page from `/poll` or `/poll/default/index` or `/poll/<controller_name>/<action_name>`. So, create `Yii::app()->createUrl('poll/default/index');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the path to

```
array('label'=>'Vote', 'url'=>array('poll/poll/index'))
```

and the page is accessible now   but I got 'No results found' which is another story

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So, you add following lines in your main.php config file:

```
'modules'=>array(
        'poll',
             ...
         )
```

and you don't have access to poll/index.php file? What notice did you have in your browser?

**EDIT:**

Maybe, if you want to generate link try this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('/poll/index') ?>">Link label</a>
```

Comment: in my config/main.php  I have                                                                                    'import'=>array(
  'application.models.*',
  'application.components.*',
  'application.modules.poll.models.*',
        'application.modules.poll.components.*',